# Replace all factor variables in each dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have three data frames with the same structure. I would like to perform the same tasks on each of them, like reformatting factor variables to numeric ones.

Let's say each data frame consists of ten variables, five of them have class factor and I want them to be numeric. Here is what I tried.

```
all.df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
factors <- sapply(all.df[[1]], is.factor)
all.df <- lapply(all.df, function(x) {
    lapply(x[factors], as.numeric(as.character(x)) })
```

The problem with that is that this way I end up with only the factor variables in all.df, whereas I still want the other (non-factor, not reformatted) variables as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
all.df <- lapply(all.df, function(x) {
                    x[factors] <-lapply(x[factors], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
                    x})

str(all.df[[1]])
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ col1: num  6 7 8 9 10
# $ col2: num  1 2 3 4 5
# $ col3: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1=factor(6:10),col2=factor(1:5), col3=1:5)
all.df <- list(df,df,df)
factors <- sapply(all.df[[1]], is.factor)
```

Comment: Calling `x` within the function after the replacement is the key.